# MKAnnotation or MKMapItem

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, mkannotation, mkmapitem

What's the difference between `MKAnnotation` and `MKMapItem`?

Which one to use when I want to display some interesting places on my map?
I have a list of objects that have `latitude`, `longitude`, `title`, `description` and `photo` so far and I'd like to have them on my map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MKAnnotation is a MARKER meant for displaying stuff using a MKAnnotationView

so the procedure is:

1. add a MKAnnotation to let the map know that there is an entry
2. wait for the map's delegate call viewForAnnotation
3. set up a annotationView there that is to be shown

a good tutorial (IMO) that shows this with detailed code is at: http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/mapkit-tutorial-for-ios-beginners/

---

MKMapItem is only for the openMapWithItem api that opens the external app!

---

EDIT: MKMapItem has a placemark property which is a MKAnnotation - so if that's non-nil you can add it. (note that it might be nil)

Comment: +1 to you for being more just as fast and even more detailed than me.

Comment: It's important to point out that `MKAnnotation` is a _protocol_ while `MKMapItem` is a class (that doesn't implement that protocol).  So step 1 should say "add an object that implements the MKAnnotation protocol to let...".  The map view wants model objects that implement that protocol.  Their _view_ is a separate thing.

Comment: "MKMapItem" has an attribute "placemark" that is of the type "MKPlacemark" which does implement "MKAnnotation" so you can add that to a map

Answer (score 2):

MKAnnotation is a protocol, used to provide annotation-related information to a map view.

I think what you really meant to refer to was a [MKAnnotationView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mapkit/reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKAnnotationView), which is used to "present annotations visually in a map view".

A MKMapItem ["encapsulates information about a specific point on a map. This information includes the map location and any other data that might be relevant, such as the name of a business at that location. Apps use this class to share map-related data with the Maps app."](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/Reference/Reference.html)

If you want to show annotations for a specific point on your map, I suspect what you want to do is use a MKAnnotationView.